# Testing the consistency of two sets of measurements

Tags: measurement-error, reliability, uncertainty

Suppose I'm measuring a quantity $X$ twice, $x_{1}\pm\sigma_{1}$ and $x_{2}\pm\sigma_{2}$. $\sigma_{1}$ and $\sigma_{2}$ are in general not equal to one another.

If I want to know if the two values are consistent with each other, I can compare their difference with the uncertainty in the difference, $\sqrt{\sigma_{1}^{2}+\sigma_{2}^{2}}$.

However, now suppose I have measurements for $n$ objects, all with different intrinsic values $X_{i}$. I measure each twice, as above. How do I say whether or not the first set of measurements is consistent with the second set of measurements?

Comment: What is consistency? Do you know the true value?

Comment: What I mean is that even though the underlying true values are unknown, that the measurements are unbiased (or biased in the same way). So I suppose I would like to confirm that 68% of the measurement pairs are consistent within 1 $\sigma$.

Comment: What is relation between $\sigma$s in comment and in question?

Comment: $\sigma$ in my comment would be the uncertainty on the difference for a pair of measurements. So a consistent pair of measurements would have a difference of less than $\sigma$.

Comment: You also do not know $\sigma$ and need to estimate from the differences. Then check if the differences are within 1 estimated $\sigma$. Following this idea, I am sure your measurement is consistent.